# Making the equation number temporarily invisible in beamer with leqno option

Tags: beamer, numbering, pause

I want to make the number of this equation visible only when the 4th line is visible.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title} 
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}[b]
      0 &= A \pause\\
        &= B \pause\\
        &= C \pause\\
        &= D \label{E:SomeLabel}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is this possible?

This code (slightly modified, with more frames at the beginning) gives the following sequence of slides:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I want the number (42) to appear only at the last slide.

Comment: Did you test your sample code before posting? You're missing a frame environment, but if I add `\begin{frame}` before `\begin{equation}` and `\end{frame}` after `\end{equation}`, I get the desired result already.

Comment: @frabjous Thank you for reminding about the frame environment, but this code is just a simplified version of another code, which I have tested, and there the equation number appears right in the beginning of the frame. I will edit the sample code.

Comment: @frabjous Now I have edited and tested the sample code. Observe the images I have added to the question. The desired result was not obtained.

Comment: @JoãoJúnior, your code works fine here. I got a 4 pages pdf file and the equation number appears only in last page (slide).

Comment: I understood the problem. It is the option leqno. With this option, the code does not work well.

Comment: I have edited the sample code again, with the option leqno. Now it certainly does not work well.

Comment: @JoãoJúnior, I agree. Problem appears now.

Comment: While we wait for experts, here is an alternative solution, not ideal, but if you have urgency... `\begin{align*}  \only<1-> {0 &= A} \\ \only<2-> {  &= B} \\  \only<3-> {  &= C} \\  \only<4-> {  &= D\label{E:SomeLabel} \tag{4}}\\
    \end{align*}`